# SQL - Index not being used for both IN and ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

In SQLite, I'm attempting to both filter with an `IN` in my `WHERE` clause and then `ORDER BY`. The columns used in the `IN` and the `ORDER BY` are both in the index, in with the column used in the `IN` coming first in the index. However, a temporary tree ends up being used to sort the `ORDER BY`, where I would have expected the index would have been used. From my reading of the [SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), I believe the optimizer should use the index for both the `IN` and the `ORDER BY`.

To be more concrete, I have a database table which I'm using to store metadata for a machine learning training dataset. The table has ~70 million rows. Each row has a column with a random integer (0-9) to allow for easily splitting the dataset into 10% chunks (for training, testing, etc). Each row also has a column to allow for a pre-shuffled random order (using UUIDs). The index is then a multi-column index on the dataset split number, followed by the random order UUID.

**In with multiple values (unexpected index usage):**

A simplified example of a desired query would look something like:

```
SELECT "t1"."tic_id"
FROM TessFfiLightcurveMetadata AS "t1"
WHERE "t1"."dataset_split" IN (4, 5)
ORDER BY "t1"."random_order_uuid";
```

Performing an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` on this reveals that the index is used to get the correct `dataset_split`s, but then a temporary tree is used to sort on the `random_order_uuid`. I would have expected the index would have been used instead of the temporary tree.

---

**Equals with single value (expected index usage):**

If instead I attempt to obtain a single `dataset_split` using an equals...

```
SELECT "t1"."tic_id"
FROM TessFfiLightcurveMetadata AS "t1"
WHERE "t1"."dataset_split" = 4
ORDER BY "t1"."random_order_uuid";
```

then the index is used for both the `dataset_split` selection and the `random_order_uuid` as desired.

---

**In with single value (unexpected index usage):**

Using a single `dataset_split` with an `IN`...

```
SELECT "t1"."tic_id"
FROM TessFfiLightcurveMetadata AS "t1"
WHERE "t1"."dataset_split" IN (4)
ORDER BY "t1"."random_order_uuid";
```

the index is once again only used for the `dataset_split` selection and the `random_order_uuid` is sorted on a temporary tree.

---

**Equals with multiple values (unexpected index usage):**

If multiple equalities are used on `dataset_split` separated by `OR`s...

```
SELECT "t1"."tic_id"
FROM TessFfiLightcurveMetadata AS "t1"
WHERE "t1"."dataset_split" = 4 OR "t1"."dataset_split" = 5
ORDER BY "t1"."random_order_uuid";
```

then the index is only used for the `dataset_split` selection and the ordering is done with a temporary tree. Notably, the [optimizer overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) states that multiple equalities separated by `OR`s will be converted to an `IN` by the optimizer, which again suggests the `IN` combined with the `ORDER BY` is the problem.

---

**In with multiple values without order by (expected index usage):**

If the `ORDER BY` is omitted...

```
SELECT "t1"."tic_id"
FROM TessFfiLightcurveMetadata AS "t1"
WHERE "t1"."dataset_split" IN (4, 5);
```

the index is used for the `dataset_split` selection.

---

Is there are reason I'm missing why the index is not being used for both parts of the query using the `IN` and `ORDER BY` together? Am I making an incorrect assumption about how the optimization works on the indexes? Or perhaps I've done something wrong in setting up my indexes/queries?

*Checked using SQLite 3.31.1*

Comment: Okay, SQLite is handing indexes exactly as expected and the way most databases do.  What is the issue?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I apologize my question wasn't clear enough. Based on my reading of the SQLite optimizer overview, I expected an index covering both the `IN` and `ORDER BY` columns would be used for both if that's all the query included. However, this didn't seem to be the case, and I'm hoping to find out why. Whether it's because I'm making some mistake (most likely) or otherwise. I also did not mean to suggest this only occurs for SQLite, it is simply the only database I've tested the conditions on.

Comment: @gomschenk . . . The comparison needs to be `=` for the next key of the index being used in general (there is an exception for skip-scans, but even those would not work for ordering by the second key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is like a phone book -- or any other ordered list if that reference is out-of-date.

If you choose two last names, such as "Smith" and "Lee", then the first names are alphabetized.  However, there is no trivial way to combine the first names to get them order by *first name* -- Zachary Lee is before Abigail Smith. Just appending them gives you two partially sorted lists.

That is what is happening with the `IN`.  The sorting information is not accurate for an index scan, so most databases just put in a sort for the sorting.

There is a mechanism called skip-scan (and I think Oracle is the only database that implements it but I will no doubt be corrected if I am wrong) that could allow an index-only optimization under some circumstances.  To be honest, though, I don't even know if Oracle would would use it in this case.

Comment: @golmschenk . . . An index can be partially used.  It does not have to cover the entire `where`.  But the basic rule is that you can use the next key when the previous key has an equality condition.  The `WHERE` in your comment can use `(a, d, b)` or `(a, d, c)` to narrow the number of rows being accessed (a fourth key, `c` and `d` respectively could be added so the value is accessible without going to the actual data).

Comment: Sqlite can do skip scans (though I have no idea if it would in this case) if the index has been analyzed: https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_skip_scan_optimization